# Why can't I db:seed when I want to php artisan db:seed

Tags: laravel

I need help in solving this problem, it seems that I cant resolve as I don't know what to do with it.
Please help in debugging this seeding error that im facing.

```
Seeding: DefaultBlockedTypeTableSeeder
Seeding: DefaultBlockedItemsTableSeeder
Seeding: BlockedTypeTableSeeder
Seeding: BlockedItemsTableSeeder
Seeding: DefaultPermissionitemsTableSeeder

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'membership.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `permissions` where `slug` = view.users and `permissions`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-auth-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673|

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'membership.permissions' doesn't exist")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-auth-master\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:63

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'membership.permissions' doesn't exist")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-auth-master\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:61

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: The table doesn't exist.

Comment: that table is not there.You should run migration before running seed command.

Comment: `php artisan mograte` then run `php artisan db:seed`

Comment: **php artisan migrate**

Comment: The table doesn't exist. You do need to run migration first before run your seeder

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing in `AuthServiceProvider.php` you define Gates that are revelent to database tables in your project (in this error: permission),So you must comment those and again run `php artisan db:seed` and after finished, go to `AuthServiceProvider.php` and uncomment Gates.